# How to use sections from other tex files?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have 8 files which I am serially listing in my `main.tex` file.

All 8 files contain one chapter.

Now I have created a `diagrams.tex` file which has 10-12 diagrams using `tikz`.

I am not including this file in my `main.tex` file.

But I still want diagrams to show up in my `main.pdf`, as well keep the chapters manageable.

Can I simply import the figures from `diagrams.tex` using one or two line commands in my chapter `.tex` files so that the relevant figures show up where I want to?

Comment: You may write your diagrams in separate files, and then include/input them as needed

Answer (score 3):

You can use `standalone` class to create your `TikZ` diagramas. With

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
...
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
...
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

each figure will be drawn cropped and placed on a different page. Then you can use
`\includegraphics[page=1]{diagrams}` where you want to include each one of them.